# How to pass multiple prams to javascript function from anchor tag

Tags: javascript, anchor

I have an anchor tag which is having OnClick event like below

```
<a id="btnSave" href="javascript: void[0];" onclick="btnSave(ID,Email ,CompanyName,address)" />

function btnSave(ID, Email, CompanyName, address)
{
  alert(ID, "+", Email, "+", CompanyName, "+", address);
}
```

in my View I am storing these values in a hidden field. I am unable to get the values in btnSave function while clicking on anchor tag. Someone please help me to solve this.

Comment: replace the `void[0]` with `btnSave(ID,Email ,CompanyName,address)`

Comment: access the hidden variables using document.getElementByID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onclick` event handler function doesn't know what `ID`, `Email`, `CompanyName` or `address` are. They are undefined variables at that point.

Retrieve the values of those fields using `document.getElementById()` and querying the `value` attribute, and pass them on to the function.

```
onclick="btnSave(document.getElementById('ID').value, ...); return false;"
```

Comment: when I am passing value using document.getElementById('ID').value,document.getElementById('Email').value  but getting only ID value in javascript not the email value

Comment: You need to make sure `document.getElementById()` receives the proper value, that is the value of the `id` attribute of the hidden field. Like, if the hidden field for email is `<input type='hidden' id='emailField'/>`, then you need to use `document.getElementById('emailField').value`.

Comment: thanks for your comments I did not add return false, as I added that its working fine.

Comment: You're welcome. Making the `onclick` event handler return `false` would prevent the browser from following the `href` of the anchor, whatever it would be. However, `onlick` would be completely ignored by browsers without JS support or disabled, and they'd always follow the `href`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing individual variable you can pass form. From form  you can get value in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
**HTML**

```
<a id="btnSave" href="javascript: void[0];" onclick="btnSave" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function btnSave()
{
    var ID = document.getElementByID('hdnID').value,
        Email= document.getElementByID('hdnEmail').value,
        CompanyName= document.getElementByID('hdnCompanyName').value,
        address= document.getElementByID('hdnAddress').value;
    alert(ID + " " + Email + " " + CompanyName + " " + address);
}
```